# Making 0.01 float work

Tags: c, floating-point

I have this function for returning money in money array. But it doesn't take 0.01. I know that it's becouse 0.01 can't be transfer in binary code precisely. But I just want it to discount 0.01. I also have line `printf("%.2f",money[15]);`showing thang money[15] is 0.00 not as I want 0.01.

```
void returning(float toReturn) {
        float money[15] = {500.00,200.00,100.00,50.00,20.00,10.00,5.00,2.00,1.00,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.05,0.02,0.01};
        int i;
        printf("%.2f",money[15]);
        printf("Pick your change: ");
        while (toReturn >= 0){
            for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                if (toReturn >= money[i]) {
                    toReturn -= money[i];
                    printf("Return: %.2f\n",money[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Do not use floats for money. Just store it as cents.

Comment: money[15] doesnt even exist for one thing, arrays start indexing at 0 to n-1

Comment: I see somebody has edited my comment - could be pennies or whatever

Answer (score 3):

There is no precisely accurate floating-point representation for 0.01.

As others have told you, the right answer here is to NOT use floating point. Use "fixed point" by switching from dollars to cents (reformatting only when you're ready to display the result to the user), which will give you better accuracy by avoiding the round-off problem. Or use a Binary Counting Decimal system, such as Java's BigInteger class, which will have round-off problems but will at least round off in a way that's more natural for humans (it'll have trouble accurately representing 1/3 rather than 1/10, for example).

Comment: I'll add to this, that the `float` format only has seven precise digits. That means, it is already impossible to discern between 170,000.00 and 170,000.01 . Not the kind of bug you want to have in your bookkeeping software!

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: Arrays: "money[15] is 0.00 not as I want 0.01." This is plainly wrong.  `money[15]` is outside legit indexes of 0,1,2,3,...14.  Code could have simple died at this point.

```
float money[15] = {500.00,200.00, ... 0.02,0.01};
printf("%.2f",money[15]);
```

Problem 2: A modern compiler with warnings turned in would have given, at least, a diagnostic for `printf("%.2f",money[15]);`  Enable all warnings or get a new compiler.

Problem 3: Mis-understanding how to use floating point numbers to represent discrete factional values like dollars and cents:
Using `if (toReturn >= money[i]) {` is prone to failure as the is no tolerance in the compare.  Say code is to work to the cent (0.01), then the compare could have been `(RoundToNearestCent(toReturn) >= RoundToNearestCent(money[i]))`.  But rounding to the nearest 0.01 is expensive and has other subtle problems too. Thus the advise to count everything in cents.  Then rounding can be quickly done to the nearest whole number with `round()`, `roundf()`.

Range:  Typical `float` can exactly represent cents to about the range $-160,000.00 to $+160,000.00.  This may work for limited uses, but `double` has an exact cent range 10 times the US national debt.

Knowing when to round:  Financial code could round to the penny after every calculation, but well written code will be more pragmatic.

```
double a,b,c;
a = 123456.0; // $1,234.56
b =      1.0; // 1 cent
c = a - b;  // rounding not needed, inputs are whole numbers, in range & subtraction is exact.

a = 123456.0; // $1,234.56
b = 3.7;  // 3.7% interest
c = round(a*b/100); // rounding needed as product is not exact
```

Some platforms offer decimal encoded floating point number, which greatly helps.  But knowing when to round is still important.